# Print text when bibliography is empty

Tags: biblatex, conditionals

With `biblatex`, I'm looking for a way to check if the bibliography is empty, and if so, print some custom text.

Something along the lines of this pseudocode:

```
\ifempty\thebibliography
    [[ no references found ]]
\else
    \printbibliography
\fi
```

I could not find any options in the [biblatex documentation](http://mirror.switch.ch/ftp/mirror/tex/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/biblatex.pdf) controlling the behavior on empty bibliographies. Did I overlook something? Is this at all possible?

**EDIT**: Here's a MWE with Ulrike's suggestion implemented:

```
\documentclass[twoside,a4paper,11pt]{report}

\usepackage{biblatex}
\makeatletter
    \def\blx@warn@bibempty{[THIS TEXT PRINTS WHEN NO BIBLIOGRAPHY IS PRINTED]}
\makeatother


\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@BOOK{hectic,
  AUTHOR    = {Henry Hectic},
  TITLE     = {How Horticulturalists Howl},
  PUBLISHER = {Honorary Books: Henage},
  YEAR      = {2000}
}
@BOOK{flutter,
  AUTHOR    = {Frederick Flutter},
  TITLE     = {Fraternising with Flowers},
  PUBLISHER = {Frippery Pamphlets: Folkestone},
  YEAR      = {1995}
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}


\begin{document}

    % Comment back in to see the normal bibliography
    %See also \cite{hectic}.

    \printbibliography


\end{document}
```

Comment: biblatex warns you if the bib is empty. You could redefine the command used for the message `\blx@warn@bibempty`.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer ... that's a bit beyond my abilities. Could you give a small example?

Comment: `\makeatletter\def\blx@arn@bibempty{Try it out}\makeatother` (put is somewhere behind `\usepackage{biblatex}` naturally) (untested as you didn't provide a complete document for a test).

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: Thanks, works like a charm. Please copy-paste my MWE above into an answer so I can mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

biblatex warns you if the bib is empty. You could redefine the command used for the message `\blx@warn@bibempty`:

```
 \usepackage{biblatex}
 \makeatletter
 \def\blx@arn@bibempty{Try it out}
 \makeatother
```